# How to get max height of bootstrap tab panel

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

My web page which is a info screen site for big screens consists of 3 bootstrap panels two on the top (left and right) and the main panel below (a tabbed panel).

It becomes some annoying that the tab panel does not fill the rest of the display (after the top panels) when clicking on the tabs.

So I need some tips on how to solve this. I need to think about many screen formats but most important big wide screens. I have searched through the net trying to find an answer but no luck yet. Hope you can help me out

regards Geir

```
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Information Screen</title>

    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700,inherit,400" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- MetisMenu CSS -->
    <link href="../bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="../dist/css/sb-admin-2.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="../bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <!--<div id="loading">
            <div id="spinner"></div>
        </div>-->
        <!-- Page Content -->
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">

                    <div class="page-header">
                        <div class="pull-left">
                            <h1> Information Screen</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="pull-right">
                            <h3 class="text-right">
                                <small><span id="divLocal">&emsp;</span></small>
                            </h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
            </div>

            <!-- /.row -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-9">
                    <div class="panel panel-default" id="UpperLeftPart">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw"></i> Key figures 1
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.panel-heading -->
                        <div class="panel-body pane">

                            upper left

                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        <!-- /.panel-body -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.panel -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.col-lg-9 -->
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <div class="panel panel-default" id="UpperRightPart">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw"></i> Key figures 2
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.panel-heading -->
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            upper right
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.panel-body -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    <!-- /.panel -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.col-lg-3 -->
                <div class="clearfix visible-lg visible-md"></div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            Basic Tabs
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.panel-heading -->
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <!-- Nav tabs -->
                            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                <li class="active">
                                    <a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#messages" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#settings" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <!-- Tab panes -->
                            <div class="tab-content">
                                <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="home">
                                    <h4>Home Tab</h4>
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile">
                                    <h4>Profile Tab</h4>
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="messages">
                                    <h4>Messages Tab</h4>
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="settings">
                                    <h4>Settings Tab</h4>
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.panel-body -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.panel -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- /#page-wrapper -->
    <!-- /#wrapper -->

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
    <script src="../bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
    <script src="../dist/js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: "the tab panel does not fill the rest of the display (after the top panels) when clicking on the tabs" - what does it mean?

Comment: Hi again. forgot some ref to JavaScript libs. Sorry about that

Comment: Still, I don't understand what you want to achieve exactly.

Comment: sorry if I was not clear enough. what I mean is I need that the tab panel borders to stretch out and take up the rest og the space to the bottom of the screen. It shall have 100% width and 100% vertical height minus the top panels. the best would be to style it with css but I have tried many things. I hope some of you have a solution on this

Answer (score 1):

You can do it that way:

HTML: I added 3 classes to identify rows and panel with tabs (you can see it on Codepen)

CSS: I set `min-height` and `overflow-y` to see the content when you browse the site on mobile devices or when height of the window is small, you can change that value and set different `min-height` on different screen sizes.

```
.panel-with-tabs {
  min-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

JS: when you resize the window, this code will calculate current window height, current height of the rows and set height value to the panel with tabs (100% of the window height minus height of the rows minus 50px to see the bottom border).

```
$(window).resize(function () {
  var heightRows = $('.row-1').outerHeight() + $('.row-2').outerHeight();
  $('.panel-with-tabs').css('height', $(window).height() - heightRows - 50);
});
$(window).trigger('resize');
```

### [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/makshh/pen/gMwMpK)